# HSQLDB "unexpected token: ( required: AS"

Tags: types, hsqldb

I want to create new TYPE in HSQLDB

```
CREATE TYPE ENUM (field VARCHAR(10), key int(1))
```

but I have mistake  "unexpected token: ( required: AS"

Answer (score 0):

This statement creates a type with two fields and is not supported by HSQLDB.

HSQLDB supports CREATE TYPE with a single type source, which results in a DISTINCT TYPE.